# Stored procedure to insert new column into table

Tags: mysql

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `student` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `score` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

Now i want to create a stored procedure that will insert new column into this table with the next id (which is automaticly created), name (value which I will write), and score (which i will write).

I have tryed

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE insertStudent (IN ime varchar(100),IN score int(11))
BEGIN
    insert into student (name,score) values (in_score,in_score);
END
;;
```

But it doesnt seem to work.

I know this is basic but i need help.

Comment: You mean insert a new *row* rather than *column*? `(in_score,in_score)` you repeat the same value here rather than `(ime,score)`, if that does not fix it what happens when you run the procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Are you inserting a *column* or a *row*?  It looks like you're trying to insert a row, which is much more conventional.

As for "doesn't seem to work", I imagine you're getting an error from the database.  What is that error?  I would guess it has something to do with unknown identifiers in the query or syntax errors.  Take a look at your procedure declaration:

```
insertStudent (IN ime varchar(100),IN score int(11))
```

And at your query:

```
insert into student (name,score) values (in_score,in_score);
```

What is `in_score` in the query?  Where do you get that?  You have a couple of problems here:

1. `in_score` is never defined, instead you have values called `ime` and `score`
2. You're trying to insert the same value into columns of two different types, that's not going to work.
3. There may be additional problems with your procedure declaration, I'm not familiar enough with SQL to say with certainty.  But `IN` and `int(11)` look suspicious to me.

Maybe your query *should* be this?:

```
insert into student (name,score) values (ime,score);
```

At the very least, even if it doesn't work that may change the error message you're seeing.  Which would be a step in the right direction.  At that point continue to examine the error message to help debug what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertStudent  @ime varchar(100),score int
as
BEGIN
    insert into student 
    values (@a1, @a2);
END
```

You forgot to put `@` before the parameter and you don't need to use `in`
and forgot to put `as`